# jQuery preventDefault() stops onclick from working

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have a problem with jQuery preventDefault from running the onclick function of an  tag. Here is my example: [Avoid page jump on # click](http://jsfiddle.net/1dcqskm0/16/)

```
$("#main a").bind("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I thought preventDefault would stop the default event (href="#"). But that it would let the "onclick" event stil fire. If I put the function inside my function it works. But I want to have different onclick functions on the links.

Comment: This isn't 1999, get rid of the inline event handlers, problem solved!

Comment: adeneo is right, you bind two clicks to a single element. One using inline javascript `onclick="..."` and the other with jQuery `$("#main a").bind("click"...`, just remove the inline one.

Comment: You can bind the click using jquery or plain js. (same @adeneo and @Jeremy). To check some particular behavior (depending the link that the users are coming from) after the event, I would do it inside the function that the event is handled.

Comment: @downvoter: The question may have been newbish, but it was in no way a bad question. He followed the "How to ask" rules and the question itself was posed correctly. It did not deserve a downvote imo.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This was some code I was cleaning up on (not mine). I would not myself write an inline onclick today after all I know about jQuery :-) But now I understand there were 2 click bindings on the element. I really was wondering because I got this to work on an <area> tag with an "onclick" function. They wanted me to add the preventDefault to avoid the page jumping on clicks. It was strange that it worked there. Here there is an "onclick" function on the <area> and I added a bind function to the area also. Seems to work here: http://uu-k1.no/kart_v2015/

Comment: Incase your issue was solved, please mark an answer as correct to close your question, or post an answer by yourself if you found a different solution. If your issue was not solved, please provide us with more info on the issue.

Comment: Sorry Dark, I checked answered now. But I still wonder why my other page worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As adeneo and Jeremy have mentioned, do not use inline event handlers. They will interfer with your jQuery event handler.

Simply merge the 2 functions into one, and it will work:

```
$("#main a").bind("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var p = $(this).position();
    $("#loader").css("top", p.top - 20);
    $("#loader").toggle();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1dcqskm0/18/)

---

> If I put the function inside my function it works. But I want to have different onclick functions on the links.

If you want to have different onclick functions on different links, then use classes (or IDs) and select them appropriately with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <p><a class="doSomething" href="#">I will NOT JUMP!</a></p>
    <p><a class="doSomethingElse" href="#">I will NOT JUMP</a></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#main a.doSomething").bind("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var p = $(this).position();
    $("#loader").css("top", p.top - 20);
    $("#loader").toggle();
});

$("#main a.doSomethingElse").bind("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    //Other code
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1dcqskm0/19/)